# how to perform crud using node.js express with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I want to perform a basic CRUD with `mysql` and I installed some modules like npm install mysql,npm install path, npm install routes  but there is a problem which I'm facing is most `middleware` error here is my

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
    var routes = require('./routes');
    var http = require('http')
    var path = require('path');

    //load customers route
    var customers = require('./routes/customers'); 
    var app = express();

    var connection  = require('express-myconnection'); 
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    // all environments
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80);
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    //app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    // development only
    if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
      app.use(express.errorHandler());
    }

    app.use(

        connection(mysql,{

            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password : '',
            port : 80, //port mysql
            database:'nodejs'

        },'pool') //or single

    );                      
    app.get('/', routes.index);
    app.get('/customers', customers.list);
    app.get('/customers/add', customers.add);
    app.post('/customers/add', customers.save);
    app.get('/customers/delete/:id', customers.delete_customer);
    app.get('/customers/edit/:id', customers.edit);
    app.post('/customers/edit/:id',customers.save_edit);
    app.use(app.router);
    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
```

and here is other customer.js

```
exports.list = function(req, res){

  req.getConnection(function(err,connection){

        var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM customer',function(err,rows)
        {

            if(err)
                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

            res.render('customers',{page_title:"Customers - Node.js",data:rows});

         });

         //console.log(query.sql);
    });

};    


     exports.add = function(req, res){
          res.render('add_customer',{page_title:"Add Customers - Node.js"});
        };

        exports.edit = function(req, res){

            var id = req.params.id;

            req.getConnection(function(err,connection){

                var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = ?',[id],function(err,rows)
                {                
                    if(err)
                        console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

                    res.render('edit_customer',{page_title:"Edit Customers - Node.js",data:rows});

                 });                         
            }); 
        };       
exports.save = function(req,res){

    var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));

    req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

        var data = {

            name    : input.name,
            address : input.address,
            email   : input.email,
            phone   : input.phone             
        };



 var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO customer set ? ",data, function(err, rows)
        {

          if (err)
              console.log("Error inserting : %s ",err );

          res.redirect('/customers');

        });                               
    });
};

exports.save_edit = function(req,res){        
    var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var id = req.params.id;        
    req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {            
        var data = {

            name    : input.name,
            address : input.address,
            email   : input.email,
            phone   : input.phone 



 };            
        connection.query("UPDATE customer set ? WHERE id = ? ",[data,id], function(err, rows)
        {

          if (err)
              console.log("Error Updating : %s ",err );

          res.redirect('/customers');

        });

    });
};


exports.delete_customer = function(req,res){

     var id = req.params.id;

     req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

        connection.query("DELETE FROM customer  WHERE id = ? ",[id], function(err, rows)
        {

             if(err)
                 console.log("Error deleting : %s ",err );

             res.redirect('/customers');

        });

         });
    };
every time when i go to cmd and run the nodo app the error occur 



 Error: Most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with Express and must
    be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middle
    ware.
        at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (C:\Users\Tahir\Desktop\node_modules\e
    xpress\lib\express.js:89:13)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tahir\Desktop\nodecrud-master\app.js:23:17)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
        at startup (node.js:119:16)
        at node.js:906:3
any body help to figure out where is the issue is ??
```

Comment: That first line in the error is all the info you need: Most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with Express and must
    be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

Comment: i saw the above given link   github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware but can u figure out please which middleware is to use ??

Comment: install the logger middleware called 'morgan' through npm. In your app.js declare a new require which uses morgan, near the top of your app.js.

`var logger = require('morgan');`

Now your error from line:23 in your app.js should not throw an error.
consider changing line:21 to be `app.use(express.logger('combined'));`

go to: https://github.com/expressjs/morgan for more configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

this code depend on express 3.4.0 version... it not work on express 4.x then express 4.x upgrade some package and middleware...... logger('dev') not work... var logger=require('morgan');... i give some more idea

uninstall express4 and express-generator
like

```
uninstall
-------------
npm uninstall express -g
npm uninstall express-generator -g
install
---------
npm install express@3.4.0 -g
npm install express-generator -g
npm express -e appname   (this is express generator)  
>cd appname
appname>npm install
appname>npm install mysql
appname>npm install express-myconnection
```

after to replace all ur code copy and paste it
 then run

```
appname>node app.js
```

all the best ........... is code really help u..